# How do I change css hover property of sweet Alert button?

Tags: jquery, css, sweetalert

I want to change the :hover property of the sweet alert confirm button.
I wrote the following code:

```
sweetAlert({
            title: "<span style='color: #134563'>[My title]",
            text: "<span style='font-size: 20px'>[My Message.....]",
            imageUrl: "images/email-icon.png",
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            confirmButtonColor: "#134563",
            customClass: ".sweet-alert button:hover{ background:'#2b5c79'; -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; }",
            html: true
        });
```

But I don't get the :hover property even with the class customization. 
How can I solve that?

Comment: Detect onHover with jQuery directly? That seems to be what they use.

Comment: there is no way to do it with the properties of the sweet alert?

Comment: I don't know if i'm doing wrong, but setting up with jquery didn't work for me

Comment: From what I can see in the options, there is none for hover.

Comment: Considering it's a dynamically added element try it with `$(document).on('hover', 'element', function() {})`

Comment: I think maybe I am trying to use the wrong selector with the jquery or something. The selector I am using for the sweet alert is: `.sweet-alert button`

Comment: @DanielaMuniz Unmarking my answer ? The "old answer" was the same as the current "approved answer"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **jquery** to *target the button* directly:

```
$(".swal2-confirm.swal2-styled").on('mouseenter', function() {$(this).css('background', 'green')})
```

**Result**:

[image]

To set the color when leaving:

```
$(".swal2-confirm.swal2-styled").on('mouseleave', function() {$(this).css('background', 'blue')})
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

You need to define the customClass as this: `customClass: ".sweet-alert button"`. Now you can define the styles in your stylesheet (css) as `.sweet-alert button:hover{ background:'#2b5c79'; -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; }`. I know the snippet does not work, it is for illustrative purposes only. You can find the [documentation here](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) or [docu sweetalert2](https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/) (examples are given).

```js
sweetAlert({
            title: "<span style='color: #134563'>[My title]",
            text: "<span style='font-size: 20px'>[My Message.....]",
            imageUrl: "images/email-icon.png",
            allowOutsideClick: false,
            confirmButtonColor: "#134563",
            customClass: ".sweet-alert button",
            html: true
        });
```

```css
.sweet-alert button:hover { 
  background:'#2b5c79'; 
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out; 
}
```

---

**Old Answer**

You can try this. Add These Events to your button, you simultate the hover Event.

```js
$(".myclass").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color","red");
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).css("background-color","transparent");
});
```

```css
.myclass {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass"></div>
```

Comment: The problem is that sweet alert creates its own structure dynamically. I think maybe I am trying to use the wrong selector with the jquery or something. The normal hover with static elements i know how to do. The selector I am using for the sweet alert is: `.sweet-alert button`

Comment: Yes, I just saw the documentation of sweet Alert 2 that you post. You are right. It works if I use outside of my project. Inside my project is sweet alert 1, maybe that works different of doesnt work at all. Thanks for the help.